# Set Humanoid WalkSpeed

Tags: lua, roblox

I found this script in a similar question but, I'm getting the error `16:11:18.560 - Workspace.Script:2: attempt to index nil with 'Character'`

```
local Player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local character = Player.Character or Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local HumanoidRootPart = character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
-- setting speed
local Humanoid =  character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
if Humanoid then
Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 25
end
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this a LocalScript or a server Script?

Comment: @Kylaaa is in a server script

Answer (score 1):

The LocalPlayer object only exists in LocalScripts. That's why your variable `Player` is nil.

There are two ways you can fix this :

1) Move this code into a LocalScript, or

2) Add this code to a callback that is executed when a player joins the game. Here's what that would look like.

```
local PlayerService = game:GetService("Players")

-- wait for a player to join the game
PlayerService.PlayerAdded:Connect( function(Player)
    -- wait for the player's character to load
    Player.CharacterAdded:Connect( function(Character)
        -- set the speed
        local Humanoid =  Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
        if Humanoid then
            Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 25
        end
    end)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or make a brick that gives you speed:

```
local KillBrick = script.Parent() 

KillBrick.Touched(function(kill)
 local humanoid = kill.Parent:FindFirstChild("humanoid")
 if humanoid then
  humanoid.WalkSpeed = 25
end

end)
```

Comment: A post like this would really benefit from some of the markdown formatting tools, please consider adding some.